# Is there a site for information recommendation?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

When I check the "help" of Super User, I found this:

> it is not about …
>
> asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation

I understand no one like ads. However, it says "learning material recommendation" rather than "for-profit learning material recommendation". So I'm wondering where can I ask for related information - this means the wanted info (mostly not the knowledge itself, but the links to documents/sites/blogs/specifications/...) is fairly broad and is generally not allowed in most of the  SE sites.

*Where can I find X related document?* is simply not an specific X question and is often closed.

The alternative - to separate this into multiple (perhaps hundreds of) specialized questions - is kind of like "polluting the site".

As for some "cold" topics, Wikipedia isn't very useful (hard to find the right entries) and  web search engines just repeat the same popular contents (of little relevance) for pages (even with extensions to block those copycats).

Comment: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24050/122193

Comment: Searching for ["learning material recommendation"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=learning+material+recommendation) turns up places where [it's acceptable](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/23049/34431) and an [answer from Tim](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1280/26390) that explains why these types of questions can become problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking if there is a site in the Stack Exchange network that works as general library (any topic in a single place) reference service (see [Reference desk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_desk)), the answer is no, there isn't.

You can find the complete list of active Stack Exchange sites at https://stackexchange.com/sites.

Each site has their own scope and policies about what is on-topic / off-topic. Some might allow questions asking for recommendations, so if you have a specific recommendation question you need to first locate the site that matches the topic of your question, then check their on-topic / off-topic help articles. i.e.

from https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic (emphasis mine)

> If you have a question about...
>
> - any natural language from a linguistics point of view
> - Linguistics phenomena during history
> - the Linguistics subcategories
> - currents, theories, and their applications in actual languages
> - linguistic analysis of specific language features or examples
> - **papers/articles on a given topic**
> - Sign Languages and writing systems

...

> ... then you're in the right place!

Related tags from Linguistics:

- [`reference-request`](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request)
- [`resource-request`](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request)

Answer (score 6):

*We are the learning material*. It’s worth understanding why we have the rule - that external links and *requests for external links* have limited value. If the links die, and answers as links go down, the resources can't be maintained. In a sense it's a refinement of the reasoning behind the '[no shopping rule](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)'. If it can be asked, the answer ought to be organic to our sites and not rely totally on other sites, and scoped reasonably so it's not a shopping list, so to speak.

> The alternative - to separate this into multiple (perhaps hundreds of) specialized questions - is kind of like "polluting the site".

But... that's exactly why the sites exist - so people can *find* answers to these questions, and if they can't and it's on topic, ask. It's better than hundreds of answers that don't make sense since they point at a dead resource. In some cases the answers give you the information you need *and* a link to the source, which is even more useful *even* if the learning material source goes down.

Comment: @ Your answer reveals the key point - SE is intended to be a knowledge database itself rather than an index of knowledge. Things get somehow complicated when more knowledge is created, and more questions are asked. Designers and users need to judge whether it's more efficient (both for creators and users) to put knowledge in a confined scope (e.g. a site maintained by related developers/engineers/...) or in an overall platform (e.g. SE).  Yet there are possibilities that SE launches a "your doc" service saying " our team will take care of your document".

Comment: @kakakali Its been tried (SE documentation, articles and even blog overflow) but honestly its not really something that's been successful so far. We *thrive* at being Q&A and being a repository of knowledge. Structured long form documentation on SE's a bit of a unsolved problem.